# cannot import some packages on android, but on ios, it's ok

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm developing game with **cocos2d-js** and **browserify**.

But as I wrote on title, `require("stream")` does not work on android.

It's really work well on iOS....

Here is my debug info

```
{
    gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
    gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
    gl.supports_ATITC: false
    gl.supports_S3TC: false
    cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 3.4
    gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
    gl.supports_PVRTC: false
    cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
    gl.renderer: Mali-T760
    gl.supports_ETC1: true
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
    gl.version: OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-03rel0.b596bd02e7d0169c10574b57180c8b57
    gl.supports_NPOT: true
    gl.max_texture_units: 96
    gl.vendor: ARM
    gl.max_texture_size: 8192
}
```

And what I want to run script : https://gist.github.com/growingdever/75dc2bb9e52a1bfdb57279c33add42cc

The version of spidermonkey(Javascript engine of cocos2d-x) is 34.

I tried changing min version or target version of android SDK to 19, but it didn't work also.

** My project works with some packages such as underscore, async, and so on. By my experience, I cannot import **[event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream)** and **dnode**. There are more packages that I cannot import. "stream" package is required by event-stream

Answer (score 0):

Use browserify@~4

I used browserify 13.0.1, but it does not seem to work for cocos2d-js android.